# Why am I getting null as the destination?

Tags: java

When I have the program print out System.out.println(_spaces.get("classroom").toStringLong()); it spits back "classroom: a large lecture hall with a door that goes null to sidewalk." Why does it say a door that goes to null? I think I have to fix my _buildPortals method, but I'm not sure how.

```
public class ConfigLoader 
{
    private Ini _ini;
    private HashMap<String, Space> _spaces = new HashMap<String, Space>();
    private HashMap<String, Portal> _portals = new HashMap<String, Portal>();
    private HashMap<String, Agent> _agents = new HashMap<String, Agent>();

public ConfigLoader(File iniFile)
{
    _ini = new Ini(iniFile);
}

public Agent buildAll()
{
    _buildSpaces();
    _buildPortals();
    _buildExits();
    _buildDestinations();
    System.out.println(_spaces.get("classroom").toStringLong());
    _buildAgents();
    //return _selectStartAgent();
    return null;
}

private void _buildSpaces()
{
    for(String spaceName : _ini.keys("spaces"))
    {
        String description = _ini.get("spaces", spaceName);
        String image = _ini.get("images", "images");
        Space spaceInstance = new Space(spaceName, description, null, image);
        _spaces.put(spaceName, spaceInstance);
    }
}

private void _buildPortals()
{
    for(String portalName : _ini.keys("portals"))
    {
        String description = _ini.get("portal", portalName);
        Portal portalInstance = new Portal(portalName, description, null);
        _portals.put(portalName,  portalInstance);
    }
}

private void _buildExits()
{
    for(String spaceName : _ini.keys("exits"))
    {
        String spaceExit = _ini.get("exits", spaceName);
        Space space = _spaces.get(spaceName);
        Portal exit = _portals.get(spaceExit);
        space.setPortal(exit);
    }
}

private void _buildDestinations()
{
    for(String portalName : _ini.keys("destinations"))
    {
        String destination = _ini.get("destinations", portalName);
        Space dest = _spaces.get(destination);
        Portal portal = _portals.get(portalName);

        if(dest == null)
        {
            System.out.println("Error");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        else
        {
            portal.setDestination(dest);
        }
    }
}

private void _buildAgents()
{
    for(String agentName : _ini.keys("agents"))
    {
        String agent = _ini.get("agents", agentName);
        Space space = _spaces.get(agent);

        if(space == null)
        {
            System.out.println("Error");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        else
        {
            Agent a = new Agent(space, agentName);
            _agents.put(agentName, a);
        }
    }
}

private Agent _selectStartAgent()
{
    for(String agentName : _ini.keys("start"))
    {
        String agent = _ini.get("start", agentName);
        Agent agentInstance = _agents.get(agent);

        if(agent == null)
        {
            System.out.println("Error");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        else
        {
            return agentInstance;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: What you have pasted doesn't seem to be relevant. How about showing the `Space` class, and this `toStringLong` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the other patterns in your code, maybe..

```
    String description = _ini.get("portal", portalName);
```

needs to be

```
    String description = _ini.get("portals", portalName);
```

If so, it's usually a good idea to extract something like this to a string constant.

`private static final String PORTALS = "portals";`

and use that in multiple places.

Answer (score 0):

Your buildSpaces method's second line is wrong. You're getting the image associated with a certain space but you have two strings in your get call and that's not right.